# Match the row height of parent and child table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a child table inside the table. There is rowspan used to to insert a new table.

Now my question is when the content of the main table cell increases, the child row of respective cell also should get extended.

Here is the table structure

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td rowspan="3">
              <table border="0" class="child_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>Sub col 1</td>
                  <td>Sub col 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Sub col 1</td>
                  <td>Sub col 2</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>Col 4</td>
   </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>When the content of this cell increases I want the 2nd (respective) row of child table also to extend accordingly.</td>
   </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/masiyijo/3/)**

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot just use one table for this?

Comment: Coz the child table should be in collapsed mode by default. To apply that expand/collapse effect I need to place those cells in different section so new table in there.

Comment: Can you add that collapsing behavior to the fiddle?

Comment: Here you go http://jsbin.com/nemajoru/3/ By default it looks like this

Comment: Is it possible to separate the each row of child table and add with parent row as child table

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yotalaqe/1/edit

Comment: have you check by giving the width of child table to 100% using css

Comment: Using jquery it is possible to set the height of inner table rows according to outer table rows.Do you want it in jquery

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lafowe/4/edit)**

```
table{
  background:#C2E5FF;
  position:relative;
    height:100%;  /* Set 100% height */
}
td{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:20%
                  /* Don't use height */
}
.child_table{
  background:#FFFFCA;
    width:100%;  /* Set width to 100% */
}
```